# How do I get the path of an open Microsoft Office program from the command line?

Tags: python, command-line

I'm writing something in python that needs to know which specific files/programs are open. I've mapped the list of running processes to find the executable paths of the processes I'm looking for. This works for most things, but all Microsoft Office programs run under general processes like `WINWORD.exe` or `EXCEL.exe` etc. I've also tried getting a list of open windows and their titles to see what file is being edited, but the window titles are relative paths not absolute paths to the file being edited.
Here's a sample:

```py
import wmi
f = wmi.WMI()
pid_map = {}
PID = 4464 #pid of Microsoft Word
for process in f.Win32_Process():
    if not process.Commandline: continue
    pid_map[process.ProcessID] =   process.Commandline
pid_map[PID]
```

Outputs:

```
'"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE" '
```

How do I get the path of the file actually being edited?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Here is a function that will return the files being edited.

```py
import pythoncom

def get_office(): # creates doctype: docpath dictionary
    context = pythoncom.CreateBindCtx(0)
    files = {}
    dupl = 1
    patt2 = re.compile(r'(?i)(\w:)((\\|\/)+([\w\-\.\(\)\{\}\s]+))+'+r'(\.\w+)') #matches files, can change the latter to only get specific files
    
    #look for path in ROT
    for moniker in pythoncom.GetRunningObjectTable():
        name = moniker.GetDisplayName(context, None)
        checker = re.search(patt2,name)
        if checker:
            match = checker.group(5) #extension
            if match in ('.XLAM','.xlam'): continue #These files aren't useful
            try:
                files[match[1:]] # check to see if the file type was already documented

                match += str(dupl) 
                dupl += 1
            except KeyError:
                pass
            files[match[1:]] = name #add doctype: doc path pairing to dictionary
```